# change bar chart to match specific colors I set in color variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I want to plot in a chart and pie chart the number of male and female users. I want the colors to match. You'll notice female in the pie chart is coral and male is light blue. It does not show up this way in the bar chart. Here is the code:

```
colors = ["lightskyblue", "lightcoral"]

f,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(18,8))
df1['sex'].value_counts().plot.pie(explode=[0,0.1],autopct='%1.1f%%',ax=ax[0],colors=colors,shadow=True)
df1['sex'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[1],color=colors)
```

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Not sure how to post a pic of the chart in here. The code above is the exact code I'm using. It outputs a pie and matching bar chart. The pie chart is two colors, which is what I want. But the bar chart is one color, and I would like to make it two colors. Specifically, I would like one bar to be coral and one bar to be light blue per by colors variable. Does this help?

Comment: No it doesn't help. The code itself is not runnable, there is some data missing. If I use some random data, I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS1NS.png) which seems to be what you want. If this is different from what you get, you need to furthermore supply the information about what library versions you are using and how you run the code. If the problem is not reproducible for others, they cannot help.

Comment: Yes! That is what I want. I am using an okcupid data set (can be found in mode). Your output is exactly what I want. How did you get the bar to match the pie chart?

Comment: I got this by running the code you show. As said previously, if you want help, make your case reproducible by clearly stating everything relevant to the issue.